# How to use Timer in multi-threaded application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have designed a Windows application using C#. The application's form consists of a couple of labels and a button. When the application starts, I instantiate a UdpListener and I start a separate thread with it, so as to achieve responsiveness while the listener waits for incoming packets. When data arrives, the listening thread needs to update the form's controls, and for this I have declared delegate functions and checking for each control if Invoking is required prior to seeing them through these functions.

The application worked fine until now. I now want to implement a timer functionality, such that if a pause of longer than 2 seconds of receiving data has been detected, I would like to turn a label red. I am trying to use the System.Timers.Timer class, and following Microsoft's example (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx), I have implemented as follows:

```
private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
```

I call SetTimer() from my main form. While the above compiles, when I try to substitute Console.... with my controls, say lblStatus, the compiler is complaining that I am trying to reference non static controls from static context. trying to build similar functions as I did for labels and text boxes and using the Invoke method checks does not work either. If anyone has implemented such functionality I would be extremely interested your opinion on this.

In regards to a possible duplication of an existing question on here, please note that I had assumed that the method and event **had** to be static (as this code was copied from the example cited above), thus the compiler error; I knew what the error meant, I just was puzzled on how I could refer to the form controls from another thread given the static nature of the event. I was also curious as to how come from that static event, Console is still accessible; I guess it's not considered a control. I hope this makes sense to the forum.

Comment: What's `ResetTimer()`? Your sample is `SetTimer`. Also, what's `atimer` - your sample doesn't declare it. Is it a member variable in the form?

Comment: aTimer is declared in my form as Timer aTimer; and is then instantiated as above in the SetTimer() method.

Comment: Why can't you just remove the `static` keyword?

Comment: remove the static keyword from where? the method, event handler or both?

Comment: Both and on `aTimer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot access non-static field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430787/cannot-access-non-static-field)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251599/referencing-non-static-fields-from-static-functions-and-vice-versa-impossible

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2565262/accessing-non-static-combbox-property-in-the-static-method

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/952023/in-c-sharp-net-how-does-one-access-a-control-from-a-static-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access member variables without an instance reference from a static function. This is because a static function is not part of an instance and it has no access to `this`.

You should just declare your `SetTimer` and `OnTimedEvent` as normal instance methods and declare the timer the same (non-static). That way all your functions will be part of the instance and will have access to other instance variables (controls).

Based on your question, it doesn't seem that you need any of these to be static.

Comment: thanks you mean that I can declare the timer as private? what about its event though...doesnt that need to be static?